# How do I detect new bars multiple times?

Tags: mql4

This EA is supposed to detect new bars and Alert some info, but it only detects the first new bar (not the next ones). Any idea why? Also, The MaxPercent function doesn't run nicely and the 'Alert' inside it doesn't show. Please helpppppppppppppppppppppppppppp.
My code:

```
    static double barOpen1 = Open[0]; 
    static double barOpen2 = Open[5];   
    
    int IsNewCandle()
    {
    
         if(barOpen1 != Open[0] || barOpen2 != Open[5]) //If any of the statements pass, a new candle must have opened changing the index number.
         {        
            barOpen1 = Open[0]; // Update variables with current prices
            barOpen2 = Open[5];
            Alert("New bar. The time is: ",TimeToStr(TimeCurrent(),TIME_SECONDS));
            return(1);
         }
         else
          {
          return(0);
          }
    
    }
    //--------MaxPercent-------      
    double MaxPercent(string Pair, int First, int Last)
    {
       double Highest = 0;
    
       for (int p = First; p <= Last; p++)
       {
       if(iHigh("Pair",PERIOD_H1,p)> Highest)
          {
          Highest = iHigh("Pair",PERIOD_H4,p);
          Alert("Inside MaxPercent(), Highest= ",DoubleToStr(Highest));   
          }
          
       };
       return((Highest/(iOpen("Pair",PERIOD_H1,Last)))-1);
    }
    //--------MinPercent-------
    double MinPercent(string Pair, int First, int Last)
    {
       double Lowest = 0;
       for (int p = First; p <= Last; p++)
       {
       if(iLow("Pair",PERIOD_H1,p) < Lowest )
          {
          Lowest = iLow("Pair",PERIOD_H1,p);
          }
       };
       return((Lowest/(iOpen("Pair",PERIOD_H1,Last)))-1);
    } 
    //-----ClosePercent--------------
    double ClosePercent(string Pair, int First, int Last)
    {
       return(((iClose("Pair",PERIOD_H1,First))/(iClose("Pair",PERIOD_H1,Last)))-1);
    } 
    void PrintDataEURUSD()
    {
    double MaxPercentD1EURUSD = MaxPercent("EURUSD", 1, 3);
    Alert("MaxPercentD1EURUSD is: ", MaxPercentD1EURUSD );
    
    } 
    void OnTick()
       {
       if(IsNewCandle()==1)
          {  
          PrintDataEURUSD(); 
          }
       }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is a `IsNewCandle()` function is called in the `OnTick()` function? I tried that on different periods and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your IsNewCandle() function should operate fine, there are however better ways of achieving new bar detection, such as:

```
void OnTick()
{
   if(TimeBar==Time[0])
   {
      //Carry out any operations on each tick here
    return;
   }

   if(TimeBar==0)
   {
      // Operations carried out on First Run only here
      TimeBar=Time[0];
   return;
   }

   // Operations at the start of a new bar here
   PrintDataEURUSD();
   TimeBar=Time[0];
return;
}
```

Your MaxPercent() function does not work because you are not passing your string properly (you are using the string `"pair"` instead the the variable `Pair`.

For example, your code

```
Highest = iHigh("Pair",PERIOD_H4,p);
```

should be

```
Highest = iHigh(Pair,PERIOD_H4,p);
```

Other lines of code should similarly be altered.